# Update last activity based on the changes in the current activity in android?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have two activities A and B. I am currently in Activity A and from A I an starting activity B. Now After finish the work on B, based on the changes in the activity B I want to update the Activity A.

Comment: what do you mean by `updating values into current activity`?

Comment: Means insert, update and delete method used in current activity and display details in last activity so if i just finish() current activity then the effect of current activity will not affect to last activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like startActivityForResult() is what you're looking for.

Example - Activity A starts Activity B with startActivityForResult().  When Activity B finishes it can return information back to Activity A via onActivityResult().

Google has a code example online: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities

Comment: no i don't want start new activity with startActivityFroResult() because i am editing and updating the screen so these two activity are for different purpose.

Comment: I apologize, I must have misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 0):

Simply Override the **onResume()** Method of your first activity to accommodate new changes.

It will work for sure :)

Comment: Read the complete life cycle of Activity through various delegate methods. Will be helpful throughout Android Project Development.